# How to sort a table on 1 column and then sort on another column in PHP

Tags: php

I have a table with 3 column, called "Prefix" , "Number" and "Name".

I have 3 arrays:

```
$Prefix, $Number, $Name,
```

which have the data that should be shown in my table. I have to say that $prefix[0], $Number[0] and $Name[0] are shown in first row and so on.

I have to sort my table, so that they are sort according to the Prefix, and then for the one that have the same prefix, they should be sorted by number.

This is an example of the data I have in my table:

```
 Prefix       Number       Name

 CIS             8         computer
 CIS            10         Managing Information Technology
 CIS            20         Data Structures
 CIS            30         Cooperative Education
 GEO            6          Managerial Economics
 GEO            12         History of Economic Thought
```

I know I can write like this:
       array_multisort($Prefix, $Number, $Name);

and they will be sorted by $Prefix, but how can I after sorting them by $Prefix, then sort them by $Number.

Comment: Can you sort it at the database level first?  Yes in theory the data can come out in any order, but in practice it comes out in the order specified by the sql sort order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you didn't indicate this in your problem description, I'm assuming that each row represents a record of data; that is, you **don't** want to blindly sort the `$Prefix`, `$Number`, and `$Name` arrays separately then display them together in a table (as above).

Rather, you want to consider each row a record and sort the records by some arbitrary ordering (e.g. Name, Prefix, and Number).

First you want to create an two-dimensional array, where the outer array will hold each record and each record is a associated array. Something that looks like this:

```
$classes = array(
    array("Prefix" => "CIS", "Number" => 8, "Name" => "computer"),
    array("Prefix" => "CIS", "Number" => 10, "Name" => "Managing Information Technology")
);
```

Then you can use `usort`, where you define your sorting algorithm to do a primary sort by `Prefix` and then a secondary sort by `Number`. All you have to do is first compare the prefixes in your comparison function:

```
function compare_classes($a, $b) {
  if(result = strcmp($a['Prefix'], $b['Prefix']) != 0)
    return result;
  if((result = $a['Number'] - $b['Number']) != 0)
    return result;
  return strcmp($a['Name'], $b['Name']);
}
```

I didn't test this, but I think you get the idea. This essentially gives you a secondary and tertiary sort. After defining this function, pass the array and the function to `usort`.

```
usort($classes, "compare_classes");
```

See this link for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php